# Set a component's input property and change it's type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that receives an array of strings, but internally I need to have an array of Foo:

```
    class Foo {
        constructor( name: string ) { }
    }
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
    @Component( {
        selector: 'my-app-boo',
        templateUrl: './boo.component.html'
    } )
    export class BooComponent implements OnInit {

        private _columns: Foo[];

        @Input()
        set columns( columns: string[] ) {
            this._columns = columns.map( column => new Foo( column ) );
        }

        get columns(): Foo[] {
            return this._columns;
        }
    }
```

But I can't do it because getter and setter must be of the same type.

How can I do this elegantly?

Comment: you cannot do it this way as getters and setters should be of same data type

Comment: yes I know I cannot, that's what I say on the question and I wonder what could be an elegant solution.

Comment: you can transform the `string`'s array to `Foo` array in the parent component then pass the `Array<Foo>` as `@Input` to `BooComponent` and define your setter like this : `set columns( columns: Foo[] )` , for me this is the elegant solution for your problem

Comment: I don't like that approach because the parent component shouldn't have to know about Foo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
    @Component( {
        selector: 'my-app-boo',
        templateUrl: './boo.component.html'
    } )
    export class BooComponent implements OnInit {

        private _columns: string[];
        private columnOptions: Foo[];

        @Input( 'columns' )
        set columns( columns: string[] ) {
            this._columns = columns;
            this.columnOptions = columns.map( column => new Foo( column ) );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 class Foo {
            constructor( name: string ) { }
        }


@Component( {
        selector: 'my-app-boo',
        templateUrl: './boo.component.html'
    } )
    export class BooComponent implements OnInit {

        private _columns: Foo[];

        @Input()
         set columns(columns: Foo[] ) {
            this._columns = columns.map( column => column);
          }
         get columns(): Foo[] {
            return this._columns;
         }
    }
```

Comment: This is not helpful because _columns will have a string[] whereas I need a Foo[]. Besides, on this case I wouldn't even need the getter and the setter, I could just put the @input on the _columns itself.